# Writing to database log in the middle of rollback

Tags: java, transactions, jboss, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I am using jboss5.1.x, ejb3.0

I have a transaction which goes like this:
MDB listen to JMS Queue.
MDB takes msg from JMS writing to Database.

in some of the catch clauses i throw "New EJBException(..)", in order to have rollbacks when specific exceptions occurs.

beside of that I have configured a re-try mechanism, after 3 times the msg going to error queue.

What i wanna achive is:

when Iam having a rollback, i want to increase the current re-try number, so if some1 is observing the database, he/she can see **on-line** the current re-try number.

the problem is: when I do rollback, so even the "insert_number_of_retry" query is being rolled back itself, which preventing from me to add the current retry number to the database

how can I solve this?

Thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to execute your logging method inside a separate transaction by annotating it with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)`.

Comment: NotSupported will also work. except it will not be done in any transaction http://www.roseindia.net/javacertification/ibm-287/manipulate_transactional.shtml

Comment: I tried @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW), it didnt work. the action was also rolled back.

Comment: if you wrap in a separate thread, it'd not matter since the thread, itself, actually starts a new transaction.

Comment: Why I must wrap it in a seperated Thread? that  is weird for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate transaction in a separate thread (you may use dedicated thread/pool for or spawn one, if need be). You have an option  to wait for the forked tx to end or forfeit (and just continue w/ the rollback and fast exit), that depends on the extra logic and so.

Comment: I may try later, haven't done any EJB since forever but instead have fixed the transaction manager (arjuna) jboss uses [it has threads leak]. One more: do NOT use the retry counter in the same entity, you need a separate entity w/ a counter and ref (and optional collection of ids of the initial requests causing the retries).