# Creating JDBC transaction for second data source with existing connection pool in Glassfish

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, glassfish, connection

I have main data source for working with database, which uses some connection pool. Now I want to create a second data source, which would use the same connection pool to perform logging operations in a *separate transaction, then main database transaction!* As far as I understood from the Glassfish [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4335/ablih/index.html) if multiple data sources are using the same connection pool, then they share a transaction until connection is not closed (I might be wrong, please correct me).

So, is there a way to start a new transaction, when getting a connection to a data source? By setting TransactionIsolation may be?

Connection is retrieved in the following way:

```
private synchronized Connection getConnection() {
        if (connection == null) {
            try {
                final Context ctx = new InitialContext();
                final DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(getDataSourceLookupAddress());
                connection = ds.getConnection();
            } catch (final NamingException e) {
                errorHandler.error("Datasource JNDI lookup failed: " + dataSourceLookupAddress + "!");
                errorHandler.error(e.toString());
            } catch (final SQLException e) {
                errorHandler.error("Sql connection failed to " + dataSourceLookupAddress + "!");
                errorHandler.error(e.toString());
            }
        }
        return connection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. It's necessary to start a new Thread, then a new transaction will be created. See also [Writing to database log in the middle of rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715333/writing-to-database-log-in-the-middle-of-rollback)